# NoSuchElementException in Scanner

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I am working on a kind-of parser (hobby project) which takes a Cpp file, reads through the comments in the file, and then tries to create a header file based on that.

The problem I am facing is when the `java.util.Scanner` is about to read the very first line. The program stops and gives me the `NoSuchElementException`. I can't really figure out what should be wrong. I checked that both path and pathname are made correctly. The file must be there, and I can read fields on the Scanner object as well when I debug. So what's the problem exactly?

Some was hinting at that it might think there are no lines in the file.

Problem occurs at `while((line = scanner.next()) != null) {`

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String filename = "", path = "";
    StringBuilder puBuilder, prBuilder, viBuilder;
    puBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    prBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    viBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(File f : files) {
        try {
            filename = f.getName();
            path = f.getAbsolutePath();
            path = path.replace(filename, "");
            filename = filename.replace(".cpp", "");
            scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        String line;
        String tag;
        while((line = scanner.next()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.startsWith(PUBLIC)) {
                tag = PUBLIC;
```

Comment: You can try changing your while loop from `line!=null` to scanner.hasNext(), then have scanner.next() inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
while((line = scanner.next()) != null)
```

[`scanner.next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if there are no more tokens available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29). You could use the `hasNext` method instead:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: It has worked before, (in multiple other programs I've made) so that's odd. I'll try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

[`Scanner.next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) throws a NoSuchElement exception if there are no more tokens.

I see that you are iterating through a list of files. Is it possible that the first file you get in that list is empty?

Can you print out the name of the file and check to confirm?