# Scanner returns NoSuchElementException from time to time

Tags: java

According to some blogposts and forum entries (e.g. http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html), one can use Scanner with \Z as Delimiter to read the whole file. Normaly, this just worked for me with this code:

```
log.debug("CSV-File: {} {}", csvFile.exists(), csvFile);
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(csvFile)) {
    String fileContent = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    log.debug("FileContent: {}", fileContent);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But some files (as far as I see all in UTF-8) can not be read this way because an Exception like this is thrown:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    ...
```

For shure, I can test, weather there is such an element, like suggested in [NoSuchElementException in Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963240/nosuchelementexception-in-scanner). But if there isn't \Z, the program does not read anything, which isn't my aim; my aim is to read the whole file into one string with as less code as possible.

I found an entry saying that this could not read the whole file: http://closingbraces.net/2011/12/17/scanner-with-z-regex/ but no entry saying that \Z could not be present in a file. Does anyone know why this happens, and weather there is a workaround?

There would be the alternative to use `Files.readAllBytes`, and construct a String from this, but therefore it is neccessary to know the charset, which I do not.

Comment: Please provide your code as well.

Comment: You need to provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem.  Code and a description of the file is critical.

Answer (score 1):

Just before using `scanner.next()`, try to test if you have things to read next string token using [hasNext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) api like:

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
   ... = scanner.next();
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Like written in the question, I could this like described inhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963240/nosuchelementexception-in-scanner but than I get nothing if the scanner has no next entry. I do not understand why Scanner does not even find one entry, shouldn't it always find at least one \\Z at the end of a file?